# Asp.net mvc 2 templates without prefix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Given following view model:

```
class DetailsViewModel
{
   public HeaderViewModel Header {get;set;}
   public FooterViewModel Footer {get;set;}
}
```

I'm using editor template for Header view model:

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Header) %>
```

The editor template (EditorTemplates/HeaderViewModel.ascx)

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<HeaderViewModel>" %>

<% ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = ""; %>

<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Search) %>
```

The result:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Search" id="Search" />
```

If I remove the line

```
<% ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = ""; %>
```

the result is:

```
<input type="text" value="" name="Header.Search" id="Header_Search" />
```

Is there another way to achieve the same - render the names of the control without prefix?

I was thinking about a helper:

```
public static MvcHtmlString EditorWithoutPrefix<TModel, TValue>(
  this HtmlHelper<TModel> html, TValue value)
{
  var htmlHelper =... // create new HtmlHelper<TValue> and set it's model to be 'value' argument

  return htmlHelper.EditorForModel();
}
```

and use it:

```
<%: Html.EditorWithoutPrefix(Model.Header) %>
```

but it is throwing exceptions.

Or maybe you know another elegant way to render names without prefix?

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to remove the prefix?  The prefix is what enables the model binder to do its job correctly when the form is posted to the server.

Comment: I hate the idea of using Bind(Prefix=...) attribute.

Comment: Can't you just use HTML.Editor("Search")?

Comment: @Brian Ball, what if you want the POST action to take `HeaderViewModel` as parameter instead of `DetailsViewModel`? In this case you need to remove the prefixes.

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I was thinking that is what denis_n was getting at, but I wanted to be sure.  @denis_n, look below, I believe I have an answer for you.

Comment: I deleted my answer below because I did not realize that Darin had posted it a while ago.  I will leave a comment on his answer about passing in null for the templateName.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [proper overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407399.aspx):

```
<%: Html.EditorFor(x => x.Search, "SearchViewModel", "") %>
```

Comment: I believe if you pass in null instead of "SearchViewModel", then MVC will use the default behavior of looking for an editor template.

Comment: this has nothing related to removing the Header prefix.