# MVC-Post Page Partially - Model Binding Fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-binding, mvc-editor-templates

I am trying to post a part of the page and bind it to view model on the controller.  My editor template for `SearchVM` :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.TestText, new { @class = "form-control ",
                 @placeholder = "TEXT" , @id="test" })
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Pencil", FormMethod.Post, 
                       new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchVM);
}
```

Controller :

```
  public ActionResult Search(SearchVM vm)
  {
     // ...
  }
```

When I type something on the `testText` text box and hit submit, I reach the action Search but `vm.TestText` is empty, I can not bind the form field from editor template to the view model. Any idea?

Comment: public class SearchVM
    {
    public string TestText { get; set; }
}

Now I am trying with  Ajax.BeginForm instead of HTML,BeginForm but same result

Comment: I think this is because you override text box Id. When you post the form, ids of inputs must corerspond to model property names in order for default model binder to work. Try removing this: @id="test"

Comment: tried it, same result

Comment: ok, then check the network tab in the browser when sending post request - what does request body look like?

Comment: thanks for the tip, helped me find the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because the class passed as the `@model` to your view wraps the `SearchVM` class, and when you call `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchVM)` it renders the input with a prefix `SearchVM`:

```
<input id="SearchVM_TestText" name="SearchVM.TestText" value="" ... />
```

In turn, when posted back to the controller, the `ModelBinder` will fail to deserialize this into a `SearchVM`

What you can do is use [this `EditorFor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4601795/314291) overload:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.SearchVM, "_SearchVM", "");
```

Where `_SearchVM` is the name of your Editor template. Passing `""` as the `htmlFieldName` parameter will remove the unwanted `SearchVM` prefix on the input.

Comment: @user2026343 If this answer solved your issue, do Stack Overflow a favor and mark it as accepted :)